# How do I pass an Event as a function parameter in HTML written inside JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am storing some html in variable after successful ajax call and appending that html to a div. Everything is fine except the event parameter. When I am passing event as a parameter of a java script function,it's appending the img html to the div but on clicking the image I am getting 'Unexpected identifier' error. Here is the code:

```
 var dataToAppend = "<img onclick='getImgSrc("+event+")' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#msgPhotoModal' class='modal-message-img getSrc' src='" + data[i].ImgUrl + "' />" +
```

When I am debugging dataToAppend variable I am getting:

```
<img onclick='getImgSrc([object Event])........'
```

and the function is:

```
   function getImgSrc(e) {
        debugger;
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        $('.msgImg').attr('src', src);
    }
```

Also var src = $(this).attr('src'); is giving me 'undefined'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should use `jQuery` to handle events. The callback is called with the `event` object.

Comment: Can you post the code that goes along your `dataToAppend` part please?

Comment: You're passing an `event` and then trying to get its `src` attribute as if it were an element. I'd try `onclick='getImgSrc(this)' ...`, using the word `this` and remove concatenation.

Comment: You cant concatenate an object with String like youre trying to do. Consider the follow: `var exampleEvt = new Event('click');
console.log(typeof exampleEvt);
console.log(exampleEvt.toString());` Try running that in your console and the results will look like what you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the `dataToAppend` variable by passing `this` directly like:

```
var dataToAppend = "<img onclick='getImgSrc(this)' data-toggle='modal'..."
```

and modify the function like:

```
function getImgSrc(obj) {
    debugger;
    var src = $(obj).attr('src');
    $('.msgImg').attr('src', src);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the `event`. An event is not the same as the element - therefore it doesn't have attributes like `src`.

First off, let's consider what the HTML needs to look like:

```
<img src="/images/MyImage.jpg" onClick="getImgSrc(this);" />
```

As you can see, the parameter is simply the word `"this"` - it won't require concatenation. Creating this HTML in JavaScript would be done like so:

```
var dataToAppend = "<img onclick='getImgSrc(this)' ... ";
```

Also, consider renaming your `e` parameter to something a bit more descriptive. `e` often refers to the `event`, but since we're no longer using that, it's a bit of a misnomer.